# How to convert string to Array via javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following string in javascript variable

```
var days="1,2,3";
```

now I want this in following way as javascript variable with JSON format like

```
jdays=["1", "2", "3"];
```

Is there anyway to do so?

Comment: You want to remove `3`? Try `days.split(',');`, or `days.match(/\d+/g)`

Comment: jdays = days.split(',') ?

Comment: @Tushar - no I don't want to remove 3, I have updated my question.please let me know if any solution.

Comment: That has nothing to do with json...

Comment: @skiskd That is not JSON, it'a an _array_, check my previous comment to get the data in the array format

Comment: @Tushar It might not necessarily be json, but it's compatible with it.

Comment: @Tobsta Yes, that's my point - _compatible with JSON_ and _JSON_ are two different things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work

```
var days = "1,2,3",
    jdays = days.split(',');
console.log(jdays); // ["1", "2", "3"]
```

`String.prototype.split()` is used to split a string into an array by removing every instance of the string passed to it as a parameter and pushing each fragment of the string to the array.

The array created by `String.prototype.split()` is the return value of the function.

Comment: FYI `console.log(jdays); // [1, 2, 3]` is wrong,  `jdays` will be `["1", "2", "3"]`, note that the elements of array are strings not numbers

Comment: @Tushar Didn't see that... Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

by using `split` function you can do this

```
 var daysArr = days.split(',')
```

Answer (score 0):

If, when you say you "want this in following way as a javascript variable" you mean you want that JSON format string in a variable.. then..

```
jsonstring = 'jdays='+JSON.stringify(days.split(','));
```